# How can I modify models.py in external app in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to modify existing model(In [Django CMS Blog](https://djangocms-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) application). There is a `Post` class, I can modify it in models.py that located inside the Django CMS Blog project, like so:

```
media = PlaceholderField("media", related_name="media")
post_title = PlaceholderField("post_title", related_name="post_title") # My code
content = PlaceholderField("post_content", related_name="post_content")
liveblog = PlaceholderField("live_blog", related_name="live_blog")
```

And after the migration the DB looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IygsH.png).
As you can see, the field is added. But how can I do that from my local project files? I don't want to add this code inside 3d party app models, because it will lead to problems with updating this 3d party app.

Comment: The best way to do this is to fork that app https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog and then use your forked version instead. From that, you could easily fetch from upstream if you want to do the upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any solutions except to copy that app to your project folder and alter it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to extend the `Post` model from Django CMS Blog in your app.

my_app/models.py

```
from djangocms_blog.models import Post

class MyCustomPost(Post):
    # This will have every field in the parent Post model, plus the ones you add below.
    my_custom_field = ...
```

Then use `MyCustomPost` (in your views, forms, admin,...) instead of using the original `Post` model.

Comment: But how can I do that? I want to replace a line '<h2>{% render_model post "title" %}</h2>' with something like '<h2>{% render_placeholder post.post_title %}</h2>' inside post_detail.html